# vim autocompletion in vimscript

Tags: autocompletion, original-vim

I wanted to make a vim snippet in my vimrc, without using a plugin. I want it to appear automatically when I type `Ctrl-N`

iabbrev was good for short code addition, as mentioned in this post
https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Use_abbreviations_for_frequently-used_words

I did not understand the
`set complete += '/user/completion file'`

I thought I would have a list of words in that file and vim adds it with `Ctrl-N`, but it did not work.

Can I get suggestion when I type `Ctrl-N`

Answer (score 1):

[`'complete'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27complete%27) is not a list of files, but a list of flags that describe where to source completions from. Specifically, you want the `k` flag:

From [`:help 'complete'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27complete%27)

> ```
> k scan the files given with the 'dictionary' option
> ```

So, like the link you provided suggests, you'll want to add the `k` flag to [`'complete'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27complete%27) and then add your dictionary files to [`'dictionary'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27dictionary%27):

```
set complete+=k
set dictionary+=/path/to/dictionary
```